# Does the Mean of a Convex Body Shift when the Body Shifts?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, expected-value, convex-geometry, geometric-probability

Suppose you put a strictly positive (supported on all $\mathbb{R}^n$) probability measure $\psi$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$. Suppose its density has only one local maximum from which the density decreases in every direction. Let $K$ be a convex body with mean $0$, i.e.

$$\int_K x\ d\psi(x)=0$$

Let $0\neq u\in\mathbb{R}^n$. I want proof that the shifted convex body $K+u$ does not have mean $0$. Seemingly, it would usually be the case that $$u\cdot \int_{K+u}x\ d\psi(x) > 0$$

Of course, if $\psi$ is uniform on $K\cup K+u$, then the claim is true and the mean would shift by exactly $u$.

However, to show the necessity of the local maximum condition, consider if $K$ is a square based cone in $\mathbb{R}^3$

$$\{-1\le z\le 3-\max(|x|,|y|)\}$$

with $\psi=\psi^K+\psi^{K^c}$ (breaking up supports) uniform inside $K$ and $u=(0,0,0.5)$, we may construct $\psi^{K^c}$ for a counterexample. Pick the conditional distributions $\psi^{K^c}_{z=a}$ to be symmetric with weight $f(z)$ (to be determined), then in order for the mean to remain at $0$, we need

$$-\int_{-1}^{-.5}z(3-z)^2dz=\int_{-.5}^3z[(3.5-z)^2-(3-z)^2]f(z)dz+\int_3^{3.5}z(3.5-z)^2f(z)dz$$

You can weight $f(z)$ heavily enough between $z=-0.5$ and $z=0$ to achieve this. It does look like it would be an unhappy distribution, so there is hope for the proposition as stated.

Comment: Of course, after sharing ideas, I often have new better ideas. I will update my question accordingly.

Comment: $K$ and $K+u$ may be identical: take for instance an infinite cylinder (filled so that it's convex), and a shift along its axis.

Comment: For now, I’m interested in convex bodies, which are defined to be compact.

Comment: Not sure if it would help, but it might: tell us why you need this kind of theorem. Perhaps there's another approach that does not require it.

Comment: I want it to work in particular for $K$ a simplicial cone (intersection of $n$ half-spaces), which is not a body. Then for hopefully every $\psi_A$ with density $(1+|x+A|^2)^{(n+1)/2}$, where $A\in \mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: Or, if you want $K$ to be compact, we could just make $K$ a centered mean $0$ simplex. Then, instead of a shift, I would want to allow linear transformations which fix one of the facets. In this case, we may also take $A=0$.

Comment: I forgot a minus! $\psi_A=(1+|+A|^2)^{−(+1)/2}$

Answer (score 0):

If I am reading the question correctly I don't think what you asking to prove is true. Suppose the measure $\Psi$ is concentrated at $0$, or, more generally, has support that lies entirely inside the intersection of $K$ and $K+u $.

With the newly added hypothesis that the support is all of $\mathbb{R}^n$ I think the result is true. It's clear in dimension $1$. That implies that the mean must move in the direction of the offset $u$.

Comment: I suspect that by writing "strictly positive" the OP wants the support to be all of $\mathbb R^n$.

Comment: Yes, there must be some change of mass at least. I made it more clear.

Comment: I have updated my question with a counterexample if you only assume support on all of $\mathbb{R}^n$